# Pyinstaller shows some error when working with mathplotlib

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hai I am trying to convert a python program to executable file (ubuntu or windows). It shows some error while doing conversion. I am adding the error screenshot with this. This error occured in both windows and ubuntu. Plese help me.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That means that the Tornado module is missing,

```
pip install tornado
```

Comment: Now the executable file is successfully created but now it shows the  belove error when I try to run the created executable file..

Comment: Are you using the stable version 2.1 of Pyinstaller or the dev version? Try with --onedir flag instead of --onefile  to see if the tornado files are included.

Comment: using the dev version.. executable file is created successfully.. but When I try to execute it it shows the error...